# Display image from image uri

Tags: javascript, imageurl

I am having trouble displaying a photo from the file URL. I am only getting `[Object HTML IMAGE ELEMENT]` on the page even though I think I am pointing this element to the image source.

```
    //database query results...
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        theID = results.rows.item(i).id;
        console.log(theID);
        theName = results.rows.item(i).username;
            htmlStr += theName;
        console.log(theName);
        thePhoto = results.rows.item(i).imagepath;
        console.log(thePhoto);

        var imageHold= new Image();
        imageHold.src = thePhoto;
        console.log("this is the src:"+imageHold.src);//THIS IS GIVING ME THE PATH

        var userDiv = document.createElement("div");//Create the div

        userDiv.innerHTML=htmlStr+imageHold;//IS THE PROBLEM WHAT I AM DOING HERE?


        document.getElementById('showUsers').appendChild(userDiv);//append it to the document
        userDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
userDiv.innerHTML=htmlStr;
userDiv.appendChild(imageHold);
```

The `htmlStr` should have valid markup.

Comment: Thanks Marcell, I am learning so I can sometimes understand what I need to do, but don't understand how to mark it up, if you catch my drift. For example, that is working, but now I have no idea how to give it size and width attributes. Is there a definitive resource for mark up conventions?

Comment: You mean give attributes to the Image? Just use `imageHold.style.[...]` to change inline style attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply use:

> userDiv.innerHTML=htmlStr+imageHold;

Instead use:

```
 userDiv.innerHTML=htmlStr+'<img src="'+imageHold.src+'" />";
```

Comment: Hi Sumit, I understand and refer you to my comment above. This didn't work and there is a syntax error - closing quote should be single I think. Thanks though.